# Are there any rest apis to perform CRUD operation on cloud messaging provided by Firebase console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

cloud messaging has list of notifications that are scheduled to be pushed to mobile devices.
Is there any way by which we can create, update, delete and view the notifications from a spring boot application without logging in firebase console separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no public API for this.  Feel free to [file a feature request](http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features) explaining your use case.

Comment: Thank you @Stevenson, could you kindly help me understand where all the notifications are stored in firebase, is it a database, is it possible to have access to this database?

Comment: As I said, there is no public API.  There is no accessible database.  Please file a feature request to indicate what you would like to do.

Comment: Thanks Stevenson, I have raised a feature request.